# How to code a "get" method template for a class

Tags: c++, templates

Traditionally, if I want to get a class's private property I have to declare a get method for it only. Now I want a get method that will return any property in its class in case the class has many properties to get. 
What I want is this:

```
function get_prop(attr_index)
input: the property's index inside class declaration
output: that property's value as constant.
```

I tried this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
class myClass{
private:
long age;
std::string name;
public:
myClass(long = 0, string = "");
template<typename T>
const T& get_prop(int) const;      //line 10
};
myClass::myClass(long _age, std::string _name): age(_age), name(_name){}
template<typename T>
const T& myClass::get_prop(int prop_index) const {
switch(prop_index){
case 1: return age;
case 2: return name;
}
}
int main(){
myClass ob1(10,"someone");
std::cout<<ob1.get_prop(1);        //line 22
return 0;
}
```

But the compiler is giving error:
[image: build message]

If i add a parameter specifying the return type like this:

```
class myClass{
...
template<typename T>
const T& get_prop(int, T) const;
...
};
template<typename T>
const T& myClass::get_prop(int prop_index, T) const {
switch(prop_index){
case 1: return age;           //line 16
case 2: return name;          //line 17
}
}
int main(){
myClass ob1(10,"someone");
std::cout<<ob1.get_prop(1,int());//line 22
return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives this error:
[image: new build message]

Can someone show me how to code it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `prop_index` must be known at compile-time. You can make it template parameter and apply [`constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

e.g.

```
template<int prop_index>
const auto& myClass::get_prop() const {
if constexpr (prop_index == 1)
    return age;
else
    return name;
}
```

then call it like `ob1.get_prop<1>()`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fYCO4D5np0Ej4V3q)

Before C++17 you can apply [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) as

```
template<>
const auto& myClass::get_prop<1>() const {
    return age;
}
template<>
const auto& myClass::get_prop<2>() const {
    return name;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DaS2Pa83O6ChUCfQ)

Comment: Thanks, but can "switch" work? If myClass has a lot of properties then "if, else" won't work.

Comment: @xceeded, unfortunately, no.

Comment: @xceeded `Constexpr if` is a special feature introduced since C++17, there's no such analogue for `switch`.

Comment: @Evg Ok. Gotta make a "if, else" hell then.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
template<std::size_t prop_index>
auto& myClass::get_prop() const {
    if constexpr (prop_index == 1)
        return age;
    else if constexpr (prop_index == 2)
        return name;
}

int main() {
    myClass ob1(10, "someone");
    std::cout << ob1.get_prop<1>();
    return 0;
}
```

This code requires a C++17 compiler.

> Can `switch` work?

In the general case, no. It is not `constexpr` unlike `if constexpr`. The return type of `get_prop` is to be deduced from all `return` statements. If all deduced types are the same type (say, `long`), it will work. If they are distinct (like `long` and `std::string`), [it won't](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction):

> If there are multiple return statements, they must all deduce to the same type.

For the same reason, plain `if` won't work either. In contrast, the untaken branch of [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) is discarded at the compile-time, and the `return` statement in that branch does not participate in the return type deduction.